# How to write tests for Android Navigation Controller

Tags: android, android-testing, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using the new Navigation Controller which is currently in alpha. It works fine but I can't find any documentation or sample app to see how testing is done. Also google published `android.arch.navigation:navigation-testing` library for testing navigation but again there is no documentation.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

Here a recent example of mine with a `FragmentScenario` and `TestNavHostController`:

```
dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:2.3.5"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.3.5"
}
```

And the instrumented test:

```
/**
 * Instrumented Navigation Test
 * @author Martin Zeitler
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class NavControllerTest {

    @IdRes
    private final int theme = R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight;

    @Test
    public void testHomeFragmentToLoginFragment() {
        
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        FragmentScenario<HomeFragment> navhostScenario = FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(HomeFragment.class, args, theme, Lifecycle.State.STARTED);

        navhostScenario.onFragment(fragment -> {

            // Create a NavController and set the NavController property on the fragment
            assertNotNull(fragment.getActivity());
            TestNavHostController navController = new TestNavHostController(fragment.getActivity());
            fragment.getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph));
            Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController);

            // Then navigate
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_loginFragment);
            NavDestination destination = navController.getCurrentDestination();
            assertNotNull(destination);
            assertEquals(destination.getId(), R.id.loginFragment);
        });
    }
}
```

Such `->` Lambda expressions require `compileOptions.sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` set in the `build.gradle`. And one can obtain the `Activity` from `fragment.getActivity()` (beware, it's not the usual one).

Comment: How to call `setViewNavController` when your `Fragment` does NOT have a View associated, but instead implicitly retrieves it via the parent `Fragment`?

Answer (score 8):

The official android documentation currently provides some detail but there aren’t a lot of examples.

In your test, you can provide a mock NavController using Mockito and can use it to verify your app's interactions.

For example, to test that the app properly navigates the user to a specific screen when the user clicks a button, your test needs to verify that this fragment invokes `NavController.navigate()` with the desired action.

Using a combination of FragmentScenario, Espresso, and Mockito, you can recreate the conditions necessary to test this scenario, as shown below:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class FirstScreenTest {

    @Test
    fun testNavigationToSecondScreen() {
        // Create a mock NavController
        val mockNavController = mock(NavController::class.java)

        // Create a graphical FragmentScenario for the FirstScreen
        val firstScenario = launchFragmentInContainer<FirstScreen>()

        // Set the NavController property on the fragment
        firstScenario.onFragment { fragment ->
            Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), mockNavController)
        }

        // Verify that performing a click prompts the correct Navigation action
        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.button)).perform(ViewActions.click())
        verify(mockNavController).navigate(R.id.action_first_screen_to_second_screen)
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't just post a link as an answer. Links expire or the content of the link might alter. Instead try to explain it and give a simple solution

Comment: @StephanHogenboom Sorry! I updated my answer - hopefully it is more appropriate :)

Comment: If you don't mind me asking: have you opted out of Winter Bash hats (clicked the "I hate hats" button)?

Comment: Did you try with arguments? when I pass bundle with navigation, my test is always failed